# How to make a a square star pattern look like a chess board?

Tags: java

I have 4 rows and 5 columns in which I want few of the stars to disappear to make it chess board like:

In First row, the second and forth stars to disappear.
Second row, first, third and fifth to disappear.
Third row, the second and fourth stars to disappear.
Forth row, first, third and fifth to disappear.

```
package starpattern;

public class square {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=1; i<=4; i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=5;j++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `if` condition to check whether it is even or odd position. If it is even then give a `space` otherwise print `*`

```
for(int i=1; i<=4; i++)
{
    for(int j=1; j<=5; j++)
    {
    if((i+j)%2!=0)
    System.out.print(" ");
    else
    System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: This will only give you columns of asterisks (each row is the same), not a checkerboard pattern. You need to include the variable `i` in your check somewhere, since the pattern changes per row.

Comment: this gave me 3 stars like 3 rows and 3 columns

Comment: Satya Thanks for helping..Actually I like this code...It's the opposite of Aderis's code...In your code the 2nd and 4th of 1st and 3th rows stars are there..Interesting!

Comment: So you guys gave me the two halves of the whole

Comment: you should even be able to shorten the code by using ``(i+j)%2``

Comment: and if you put       " if((i+j)%2!=0)", you will make its opposite ! awesome

Answer (score 2):

```
final int numRows = 4;
final int numCols = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++)
    {
        //the places where '*' is printed is where the row and col add to an even number
        String s = (((i + j) & 1) == 0) ? "*" : " ";
        System.out.print(s);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: I got a problem with this.. It prints one star at each line lined up on one column

Comment: whoops, made it a `println` instead of `print`. I changed my answer to work properly.

Comment: hey what do you think about this? although this is full of errors but I wonder if it can be fixed somehow?for(int i=1; i<=4; i++)
  {
   for(int j=1;j<=5;j++)
   {
    if(int i=1 && int i=3)
    {
     if(int j=1 && int j=3 && int j=5)
     {
      System.out.print("*");
     }
    }else{
     System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
     
    
   }
   
  }

Comment: I know it looks horrible sorry

Comment: @MarieMirbekian The code you just provided has the following errors: When you write an if statement, you do not need the `int` before each expression, and you need a `==` instead of `=`. What you are doing in your if statements is essentially creating multiple different variables of the same name and assigning them all different values. Also, in your if statements, I assume you want `||` operators instead of `&&`, since `i` and `j` cannot have multiple values at the same time, meaning the if statements will never evaluate to true. These are just the syntactic things giving the compiler errors.